# Is the ship's captain required to report laptop/mobile serial numbers for all passengers and crew?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, passenger-rights, ships

A *privately owned* *ketch* on tour in the South Pacific is planning to make landfall in Australia early next week and it is carrying about a dozen of the captain's friends and family.

Of course the captain will have to report to the harbour master (and ultimately the [DIBP](https://www.border.gov.au/)) with everyone's passports (that's a given). It's also understood that he will have to provide the make and serial number of his [EPIRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_position-indicating_radiobeacon_station) and radar.  But is the captain also required to list the make and serial number of everyone's laptop and mobile?

Comment: This seems more like a specialist question on maritime law than a travel question. But surely if there was some law like this then it would apply to cruise ships and ferries too and then everyone would know about it?

Comment: @Jonathan common carriers often have different requirements from private vessels.  As a not-very-closely-related example I can cite the fact that otherwise-eligible travelers cannot use the VWP to enter the US on a private airplane or boat.

Comment: @phoog If the private plane is flown by a VWP approved carrier, then they can. There are many air charter companies which have registered for the VWP for just this purpose. It is not very common (mainly because most GA in the US is domestic) but it is a thing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I wouldn't have thought that a plane flown by an air charter company -- carrying passengers for hire -- would count as a "private plane."

Comment: @phoog Right, you can't just go out as a _private_ pilot, hop in your _personal_ plane and bring your friends back to the US from overseas -- unless they have visas. But if you're flying on a private plane, unless you personally know the pilot it's likely going to be under the auspices of some sort of company.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I like to do that a lot. A whole lot. But I'm always prepared with either a passport or a visa.

Comment: @GayotFow you're not eligible for the VWP anyway!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, please see [Smallcraft Arrival Report](https://www.border.gov.au/Forms/Documents/b333.pdf). Clip below:

[image: TSE78326 example]

It seems clear from the number of slots and inclusion of `TV, Stereo, etc.` they mean more than just the navigational equipment on board. Mobile telephones is a bit more doubtful but I do know Australia likes to control these more closely than most countries.

Comment: Why would Australia control mobile phones moreso than another country? (This may be an obvious question, but occasionally I revert to the ignorant American of stereotype....)

Comment: Very useful. A print-out of this question/answer is being emailed as we speak.  I assume that iPads, Kindles, and what-not fall into the same category as laptops and that mobiles can be itemised without much additional effort.

Comment: Typical Aussie bureaucracy gone nuts. Needless to say, if you fly in by air, Customs has better things to do than ask for your mobile phone's serial number...

Comment: @jpatokal They do however ask about the total value of your electronics (that have not been used by you for more than 12 months) on your customs declaration. Exceeding value of $900, exceeds your duty-free allowance and if they opt to check, you are liable for fines ***and*** duty. (ie. An iPhone 6S+ in Japan costs over AU$1000 and if customs decided to check (which as you seem to agree, 99% of the time they don't), you would be liable for duty).

Comment: @pnuts You don't get fined for declaring something, but you will be obliged to pay tax on every item you have that was otherwise duty free assuming you exceed your duty free allowance. You only get fined when failing to declare.

Comment: @pnuts That seems odd. If you declared it you aren't meant to be fined unless they find something you didn't declare. What airport were you going into?

Comment: @pnuts I have never found anything on either the Australian Customs site or through talking to customs officials (when I worked at PER a few years ago) that mentions declaring and getting fined (in fact I have been told you don't get fined if you declare, otherwise there would be no point in declaring). Did you try to appeal? Because it sounds like you got picked out for some reason.

Comment: @pnuts That all sounds real shady. Maybe someone was trying to fill their quota for the day. It wouldn't be beneath some of them.