# Landing in Australia without a Visa

Tags: australia, visas-on-arrival, removal, russian-citizens

In the same narrative as [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78326/is-the-ships-captain-required-to-report-laptop-mobile-serial-numbers-for-all-pa), a private ketch sailing the South Pacific will make landfall in Australia about midday on Tuesday (13 Sept 2016). As they were preparing their documents, the captain grew worried that one of the passengers is a Russian national, i.e., a person who would normally need a visa to land in Australia.  It's not a case of a stowaway, she is an invited guest.

She has a US Tourist Visa which is still valid and joined the cruise in Hawaii several weeks ago. Nobody thought to consider the bigger picture. Their previous port of call was Honiara where, apparently, the party was able to land without producing travel documents.  I suspect Australia will be more rigorous.  It's too late to turn around and yeah, everybody should pay more attention to these things, but sometimes it happens. I have no clue about corner cases arising under the Australian system.

So what happens now? Can she get a visa-on-arrival? Or she be unable to land? Or worse, taken into detention?  Or is it OK given they already landed in Honiara and she has a current US tourist visa?

Comment: If it matters they plan to first visit Thornton Beach and then finally to anchor and resupply in Moreton Bay'

Comment: @pnuts Criminey. OK, write it up please, can you land after paying the fine I wonder? 600 quid is not the end of the world if it results in a happy ending.

Comment: I also know nothing myself, but during random web page searching I found this: [You must be outside Australia when the Electronic Travel Authority visa is granted or, if you apply for it while you are in immigration clearance, then you must be in immigration clearance at the time it is granted.](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visi/Visi)

Comment: While US citizens are eligible for an Electronic Travel Authorization, Russians are not, and her US visa may be of little use. However, Russian passport holders may apply online for the Visitor e600 visa (and before arriving in Australian waters).
https://australianvisaauthority.org/visa-form-application/

Comment: @pnuts slightly different: US passports holders are in subclass 601 and the Electronic Travel Authority seems to be granted within 24 hours, or less. Russian passport holder is visitor visa subclass 600. I've yet to find how long before being granted, but it could create a bit of an advantage since the craft plans to arrive very shortly.

Comment: @pnuts here's the list link (yet to figure out how to do the link in a comment) http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-e600-visa-online-applications

Comment: @pnuts I also referenced the reverse Wikipedia/Russia/visa https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Russian_citizens

Comment: @pnuts her visa may be granted within one day https://www.border.gov.au/about/access-accountability/service-standards/visitor-visa-processing-times

Comment: @pnuts low risk, as little as one day, high risk, up to a week, and, with a US visa, probably low risk

Comment: Great news @Dorothy please write it up. I have already learned from the link provided by pnuts (to whom thanks) that Thornton Beach is unsuitable. Moreton Bay looks ok.

Comment: @pnuts "Your" list is not an official list. The site you linked is a UK limited company, not an official Australia government site.

Comment: @pnuts If someone as experienced as you can be fooled by a site like that (which I admit looks fairly government-ish) then most people are going to be hopelessly screwed if such sites happen to have wrong information.

Comment: @MichaelHampton this one's a dodge that gets linked to all the time. Even here! http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/  run a whois on it :)

Comment: @GayotFow That site is owned by [this guy](https://www.linkedin.com/in/besartbajrami). His LinkedIn should tell you everything you need to know about his web sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While US citizens are eligible for an Electronic Travel Authority, Russians are not, and her US visa may be of little use. However, [Russian passport holders](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-e600-visa-online-applications) are among those eligible to [apply online for a Visitor e600 visa](https://australianvisaauthority.org/visa-form-application/).

[Visa processing times](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-e600-visa-online-applications) in this class can be as little as 24 hours and, with luck, hers may be granted before the craft reaches Australian waters.

Makani 'olu a holo mālie

Comment: I know of people who have waited for a month to get their e600. Speaking of which, ETA is also non-instantaneous sometimes and I would double check if the crew has had theirs approved.